# File splitting and distribution using spring integration

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-integration

My requirement is to split a large file(containing millions of records) into 100K records files and distribute them to 3 folders. I have used Java to split the file and spring integration to distribute them. During the process it takes long time to distribute the files into folders. Have added the configuration files below. Is the usage of spring integration bridge correct for this purpose or is there any optimized way? I need to enhance this code to read and write files to s3 buckets instead of local directories in future. Will the s3 inbound/outbound adapters support the same purpose?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd">


<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn1"
    directory="/tmp/test">
    <integration:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

 <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut1"
    directory="/tmp/output" delete-source-files="true" />

<integration:service-activator
    input-channel="filesIn1" output-channel="filesOut1" ref="handler" />


<bean id="handler" class="com.test.Handler" />


<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn2"
    directory="/tmp/output" filename-pattern="stack1*">
    <integration:poller id="poller1" fixed-delay="5000" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut2"
    directory="/tmp/stack1" delete-source-files="true" />
<integration:bridge input-channel="filesIn2" 
        output-channel="filesOut2" />


<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn3"
    directory="/tmp/output" filename-pattern="stack2*">
    <integration:poller id="poller2"  fixed-delay="5000"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut3"
    directory="/tmp/stack2" delete-source-files="true" />
<integration:bridge input-channel="filesIn3" 
        output-channel="filesOut3" />


        <file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn4"
    directory="/tmp/output" filename-pattern="stack3*">
    <integration:poller id="poller3" fixed-delay="5000" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut4"
    directory="/tmp/stack3" delete-source-files="true" />
<integration:bridge input-channel="filesIn4" 
        output-channel="filesOut4" />
```

Handler.java

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

   public class Handler {
    public void handleFile(File input) {
        System.out.println("Copying file: " + input.getAbsolutePath());

        try {

            Path p = Paths.get(input.getAbsolutePath());
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(p);

            int count = lines.size();
            System.out.println("Lines in the file: " + count);
            lines.size();// Source File Name.
            Long nol = 100000L; // No. of lines to be split and saved in each
            int stackcount = 0;

            Long temp = (count / nol);
            Long temp1 = (Long) temp;

            Long nof = 0L;
            if (temp1 == temp) {
                nof = temp1;
            }
            else {
                nof = temp1 + 1;
            }
            System.out.println("No. of files to be generated :" + nof); // Displays
                                                                        // no.
                                                                        // of
                                                                        // files
                                                                        // to be
                                                                        // generated.

            // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            // Actual splitting of file into smaller files

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(input.getAbsolutePath());
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;

            for (int j = 1; j <= nof; j++) {

                if (stackcount < 3) {
                    stackcount = stackcount + 1;
                }
                else {
                    stackcount = 1;
                }

                FileWriter fstream1 = new FileWriter("/tmp/output/stack" + stackcount + "-" + j + ".dat"); // Destination
                                                                                                           // File
                                                                                                           // Location
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream1);

                for (int i = 1; i <= nol; i++) {
                    strLine = br.readLine();
                    if (strLine != null) {
                        out.write(strLine);
                        if (i != nol) {
                            out.newLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
                out.close();
            }
            in.close();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: First of all using `Files.readAllLines(p)` for counting number of lines in file (as you said - million of records) is terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the usage of spring integration bridge correct for this purpose or is there any optimized way?

You can go this way. It's fine. But if you switch to the `channel` attribute on both inbound and outbound channel adapters you don't need that `<bridge>`

> Will the s3 inbound/outbound adapters support the same purpose?

Correct. They really provide similar functionality but for AWS S3 protocol.

Note: your config isn't clear and looks like it isn't related to the question...

Answer (score 0):

As Andremoniy said in comment to question, using `Files.readAllLines` is not something you will actually want - presumably, your memory is unable to hold this much at once.

So instead, why not try this:

```
try(Stream<String> allLines = Files.lines(path)) {
  Iterator<String> reader = allLines.iterator();

  int splitBatch = 10000; // however much you need.
  int lineCount = 0;
  int batchNumber = 1;
  FileWriter out = getBatchOut(batchNumber); // replace this with what you need.
  while(reader.hasNext() && lineCount < splitBatch) {
    if (lineCount == splitBatch) {
      out.flush(); out.close();
      out = getBatchOut(++batchNumber); // next batch
      lineCount = 0;
    }
    out.write(reader.next());
    lineCount++;
  }
}
```

**Note** I did not include any exception handling in my example code. You should always remember to release all resources when encountering an exception. In my example, `out` writer must always be closed to not introduce memory leaks. I'll leave it to you how to do this correctly and when.